# How Do I Run update-perl-sax-parsers to get XML::LibXML::Document properly installed?

Tags: updates, perl, xml

I've just tried to install the Perl module XML::LibXML::Document using the cpan shell and at the end of the process it says:

```
Please use 'update-perl-sax-parsers(8) to register this parser.'
See /usr/share/doc/libxml-sax-perl/README.Debian.gz for more info.
```

If I run `update-perl-sax-parsers` with no arguments it returns almost instantly with no output (and I still can't use `XML::LibXML::Document` within Perl)

If run '`update-perl-sax-parsers -help`' I can see I probably need to specify the `--directory` flag or the `--file` (although they have defaults)

Perhaps I missing something but I can't see where in README.Debian.gz it tells me what options I need either.

What step am I missing?

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04, Perl 5.14, CPAN shell v1.960001

Let me know if this is more suited to stackoverflow.

Comment: Does `man update-perl-sax-parsers` get you anything useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XML::LibXML::Document` is just a `XML::LibXML` DOM Document Class.

You can't use it directly, only `use XML::LibXML;` is required.

first type `sudo update-perl-sax-parsers --update`

An you can quickly check that the following command works:

```
perl -e 'use XML::LibXML; $dom = XML::LibXML::Document->new( $version, $encoding );'
```

Comment: Great, thanks. The problem was a combination of me trying to use the Document class directly, plus (I don't think) the docs for update-perl-sax-parsers are very clear. I'll see if I can suggest a change.